# jruby include java class performance vs include a package

Tags: module, jruby, jrubyonrails

I have a jruby rails app with a ruby module in lib that is name-spacing my java objects so I don't have conflicts.

I'm wondering what the difference is between including the specific classes in that module and including the package.  I've included the sample code below.

In the console, for *example 1* when I say MyMod:: and hit tab, it has (for example) 101 methods and class options with MyMod::MyClass being one of them.

For *example 2*, when I hit MyMod:: and tab, it only has 100 method/class options and it doesn't contain MyClass.  If I then go and reference MyMod::MyClass, then run that MyMod:: tab again, I now have 101 options and MyClass is listed.

Here's my question.  What's the difference between referencing these classes immediately in my module à la *example 1* vs having them load on demand like *example 2*.  If I have a package with about 20 classes that I use, is it preferred to have them loaded on demand or up front, and is there any overhead to loading this on demand, à la *example 2*

**Sample Code:**

*example 1*

```
module MyMod
  MyClass = Java::my.package.MyClass
  ....
end
```

vs
*example 2*

```
module MyMod
  include_package "my.package"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really are going to use a class, it is going to cost you something at some point. It doesn't matter whether loading it specifically or on-demand. I think for your 2 examples, if you do use `MyClass`, then there's no difference. On the other hand, if `MyClass` is never used, then example 1 is clearly wasting something.

Also, `include_package` does not really pull the whole package in, but kind of like establishing a search scope when needing a class. Generally it is not recommended to use `include_package`. See [JRUBY-2376](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-2376?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) for problems it has.

Comment: Great thanks.  I'm not really extending or overriding any java code in my ruby, which is what that bug seems to pertain to, I'm literally just including the packages so I can reference them, good to know though.

Answer (score 0):

I got slightly different results.  Perhaps you're using a different auto-completer?

```
irb(main):001:0> module MyMod;MyClass = Java::JavaUtil::Date;end
=> Java::JavaUtil::Date
irb(main):002:0> module OtherMod;include_package "Java.Util";end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> MyMod.methods.size
=> 109
irb(main):004:0> OtherMod.methods.size
=> 109
irb(main):005:0> require 'irb/completion'
=> true
irb(main):006:0> MyMod::
Display all 110 possibilities? (y or n)
irb(main):006:0> OtherMod::
Display all 109 possibilities? (y or n)
irb(main):006:0> OtherMod::
irb(main):007:0*
```

As to your question, I don't know for sure.  But if I had to guess, d'd say that as ruby is dynamic, neither approach loads anything up-front.

Comment: I'm using rails console.  I just tried your example with two rb files created to your spec with the same results, however methods doesn't seem to list the available classes to that module.  Here's some output from my console  
>> MyMod.methods.size  
=> 161  
>> OtherMod.methods.size  
=> 161  
>> MyMod::<tab>  
Display all 162 possibilities? (y or n)   
>> OtherMod::<tab>  
Display all 161 possibilities? (y or n)

Comment: oops... that doesn't format too well, i think you get it though >> is obviously the console prompt